# Xamarin Android HttpClient.GetAsync only works in Wifi but not mobile data?

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httprequest

I've met a strange problem recently. I have Xamarin Android project, every time I call http request using real device with mobile data, it will throw me HttpRequestException, if I am using WiFi, everything is good.

My code of calling HttpRequest is

```
var url = "some/parameter"
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx");
await client.GetAsync(url);
```

Following is the detail of HttpRequestException:

Inner Exception: `{System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c8] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/a…}`

Error Code: 11001
Message: No such host is known
SocketErrorCode: HostNotFound

StackTrace as below:

```
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00180] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:84 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ea] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:385 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:543 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:284 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506
```

I have included these in my Android.Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

My mobile data connection is good as I still can access other app using mobile data, I have no idea why there is difference between using WiFi and mobile data especially HttpRequest? What can I do to fix this problem in my project? Any help?

Comment: Just a suggestion - could it be that you try to use a service located in local network/intranet?

Comment: "HostNotFound" seems pretty obvious.  You are most likely connecting to a local server that is available over your local WiFi but not available via your cell network.

Comment: Unfortunately the local server is managed by other customer, is there any way to configure this in my code?

Comment: @ShengJie Hi, unless the local server use public IP, mobile data will not visit it.

Comment: Means the server is currently using private IP, so mobile data cannot visit it but WiFi can?

Comment: @ShengJie No, if wifi is the same with server, you can. But mobile data always can not.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT so I can't do anything on my code?

Comment: @ShengJie Yes, that's the problem from local server, it not supports for mobile net.

Comment: I see, thank you @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I guess I have to do something on the server

Comment: im having the same issue with mine. i have it set to try a local ip address and then a remote domain name, and use the faster one. it times both connections succussfully under wifi. with wifi off, the first fails as expected, but so does the second. if i type the second address into a browser, it works fine on wifi or data. if i put the same phone on a different, external wifi (home) it can still connect to the remote address on the work wifi, without an issue.  it works perfectly in every way on any network, but not on mobile data.

Comment: A customer is having the same issue. He can access the url using a mobile browser on the same device.